# PHP keep getting the wrong SQL return values

Tags: php, sql

Hey I'm wanting to retrieve some data from the a database. But it seems no matter what values I enter into my SQL database I always return with "Password is incorrect" statement embedded in my code. (It's down the better for reference and returns 1). Can anybody see anything wrong with my code where $pw will always return 1?

Comment: Why don't you print or echo the values from variables $pw and $password to see if matches? to me it seems like their values are distinct...

Comment: I would print their values in the line where you echo "Password Incorrect."

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "print their values"? As doesn't return 1 mean that the password that has been entered is incorrect? and therefore not correct? If I print there value in return 1 it doesn't make the answer anymore correct? Sorry that's just from my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `$pw` so it takes the correct password from the database as in:

```
 $pw = OCIResult($stmt,"PASSWORD");
```

instead of trying to get the value of the column 1 as in your example since i believe you are returning something else (propably the username following your other questions) by referencing column 1.

Comment: Hmm it still seems to be giving me "Password is incorrect". Instead of "You have been logged in!" when a correct PW and username is used. Ill keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

Try change this line:

```
echo "Password is incorrect. \n";
```

for this:

```
echo "Password is incorrect.".$pw.";".$password;
```

And comment the result